# GeckoFx version 22 GeckoWebBrowser.DrawToBitmap in windows 7 64bit Environment

Tags: geckofx

I am a developers from China, when I use GeckoFx, I  encountered a problem.
I use GeckoFx version 22, when I use GeckoWebBrowser.DrawToBitmap method in Windows 7 64 bit environment, I can not get the snapshot,on get a gray box. If I use the normal WinForm control, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone will give you an answer for GeckoFX 22. There are [two issues](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0/issues?q=image) related to capturing images at the bitbucket site. Neither were resolved. It's possible that it just didn't work.

In case it is helpful, here's how we do it using GeckoFX 29:

```
private Image CreateImage(GeckoWebBrowser browser)
{
    var creator = new ImageCreator(browser);
    byte[] imageBytes = creator.CanvasGetPngImage((uint)browser.Width, (uint)browser.Height);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

Looking at the source of [ImageCreator class](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/src/a4818f246c983506f26072c005a54143700f6c49/Geckofx-Winforms/Utils/WindowsImageCreator.cs?at=default) , I see there are now calls that would be simpler, like

```
ImageCreator.CapturePng(browser);
```